# Why is the service unavailable the second time?

Tags: process, debugging

How can this happen?

```
/volume1/homes/me $ tdtool --list
/volume1/homes/me $ tdtool -e 44
Learning device: 44 - Could not connect to the Telldus Service
/volume1/homes/me $ tdtool --list
Error fetching devices: Could not connect to the Telldus Service
/volume1/homes/me $
```

`tdtool` is using a daemon `telldusd`. The first time `tdtool --list` works but a few seconds later the same command fails, the service is not available any more. Using command `ps`, I can see that the process is still alive. How do I troubleshoot what is going on?

Comment: Does `telldusd` write a log file anywhere?  Does it say anything useful?

Comment: Have you asked support at [Telldus](http://www.telldus.com/)

Comment: egrep 'tell|td' does not reveal anything in the /var/log directory. Unfortunately Linux is not very well supported from Telldus. They consider Windows being the main track. I have asked in their forum but I didn'd get any response. I thought this was a more wellknown general issue where I lack knowledge.

Comment: What does this do? Is is *really* that essential that you can't do without? (From what you say, support is utter crap; and the behaviour you describe smells awfully of severe bugs.)

Comment: It's to control a Tellstick, which is intended to send signals to remote controlled light switches etc. I have run it on Windows but I want the server to run on Linux since I don't want a noisy energy hungry PC running 24/7. Instead I have a Synology NAS that should be perfect for the task.

Comment: So, this isn't an answer, but my guess is that if you want to figure out what is going on and it isn't logging, you will need to dig in a bit.  How does tdtool talk to the daemon?  A network port, an AF_UNIX socket, something else?  If you aren't sure, I would try (1) run lsof on the daemon and see what files and sockets it opens.  Do their state change after the first connection?  (2) start the daemon in the forground and run it under strace.  In another shell run tdtool, perhaps under strace as well.